# rospack failed to build in Hydro, can't find PythonLibs

Tags: python, ros-hydro, mavericks, rospack, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed the [instructions to install Hydro from source for OSX](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source) and `rospack` fails to build because it cake can't seem to find PythonLibs. The full out put is shown below:

```
[nina@Dalek ros_catkin_ws]$ ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated
--install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --install-space /opt/ros/hydro Base path: /Users/nina/tmp/ros/ros_catkin_ws Source space: /Users/nina/tmp/ros/ros_catkin_ws/src Build space: /Users/nina/tmp/ros/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated Devel space: /Users/nina/tmp/ros/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated Install space: /opt/ros/hydro Additional CMake Arguments:
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~  traversing 48 packages in topological order: ~~  - catkin ~~  - genmsg ~~  - gencpp ~~  - genlisp ~~ 
- genpy ~~  - console_bridge (plain cmake) ~~  - cpp_common ~~  - message_generation ~~  - message_runtime ~~  - mk ~~  - ros ~~ 
- ros_comm ~~  - rosbash ~~  - rosboost_cfg ~~  - rosbuild ~~  - rosclean ~~  - roscpp_traits ~~  - roscreate ~~  - rosgraph ~~  - roslang ~~  - roslisp ~~  - rosmake ~~  - rosmaster ~~  - rosmsg ~~  - rospack ~~  - roslib ~~  - rosparam ~~  - rospy ~~  - rosservice ~~  - rostime ~~  - roscpp_serialization ~~  - rosbag_storage ~~  - roslaunch ~~  - rosunit ~~  - rosconsole ~~  - rostest ~~  - std_msgs ~~  - rosgraph_msgs ~~ 
- std_srvs ~~  - xmlrpcpp ~~  - roscpp ~~  - rosout ~~  - message_filters ~~ 
- rosnode ~~  - rostopic ~~  - roswtf ~~  - topic_tools ~~  - rosbag ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

==> Processing catkin package: 'catkin' Makefile exists, skipping explicit cmake invocation...
==> make cmake_check_build_system in '/Users/nina/tmp/ros/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin'
==> make -j4 -l4 in '/Users/nina/tmp/ros/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin'
==> make install in '/Users/nina/tmp/ros/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin' Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "Release"
-- Installing: /opt/ros/hydro/.catkin
-- Installing: /opt/ros/hydro/_setup_util.py
-- Installing: /opt/ros/hydro/env.sh
-- Installing: /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash
-- Installing: /opt/ros/hydro/setup.sh
-- Installing: /opt/ros/hydro/setup.zsh

... other output ...

==> Processing catkin package: 'rospack'
==> Building with env: '/opt/ros/hydro/env.sh'
==> cmake /Users/nina/tmp/ros/ros_catkin_ws/src/rospack
-DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/Users/nina/tmp/ros/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rospack
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/hydro -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release in '/Users/nina/tmp/ros/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/rospack'
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /Users/nina/tmp/ros/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rospack
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/hydro
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/hydro
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Python version: 2.7
-- Using default Python package layout
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /Users/nina/tmp/ros/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/rospack/test_results
-- Found gtest: gtests will be built CMake Warning (dev) at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/tools/doxygen.cmake:40 (GET_TARGET_PROPERTY):   Policy CMP0045 is not set: Error on non-existent target in   get_target_property.  Run "cmake
--help-policy CMP0045" for policy details.   Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  get_target_property() called with non-existent target "doxygen". Call Stack (most recent call first):   /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/all.cmake:139 (include)   /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:20 (include)   CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package) This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- catkin 0.5.88
-- Boost version: 1.55.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   filesystem
--   program_options
--   system CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.0.0/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:136 (message):   Could NOT find PythonLibs (missing: PYTHON_LIBRARIES PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS)   (Required is at least version "2.7") Call Stack (most recent call first):   /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.0.0/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:343 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)   /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.0.0/share/cmake/Modules/FindPythonLibs.cmake:197 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)   CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! See also "/Users/nina/tmp/ros/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/rospack/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log". <== Failed to process package 'rospack':    Command '/opt/ros/hydro/env.sh cmake /Users/nina/tmp/ros/ros_catkin_ws/src/rospack
-DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/Users/nina/tmp/ros/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rospack
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/hydro -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release' returned non-zero exit status 1

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /Users/nina/tmp/ros/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/rospack && /opt/ros/hydro/env.sh cmake /Users/nina/tmp/ros/ros_catkin_ws/src/rospack
-DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/Users/nina/tmp/ros/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rospack
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/hydro -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release

Command failed, exiting.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/175612/rospack-failed-to-build-in-hydro,-can%27t-find-pythonlibs/) by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2962 on 2014-06-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-06-28**:
Gosh, cmake 3.0.0, that is terrifying. I'm not convinced that is the problem, but are you using the System python or one installed from Homebrew?

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2014-06-28**:
When I updated brew, it installed cake 3.0.0. Yes, I am using python 2.7.5 that comes with Mavericks.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-06-28**:
Looks similar to https://github.com/ros-visualization/qt_gui_core/pull/45

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, it appears to due to cmake 3.0. In rospack/CMakeLists.txt, remove/comment out:

```
set(PythonLibs_FIND_VERSION "${PYTHON_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PYTHON_VERSION_MINOR}")
find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)
```

and add/replace with:

```
find_package(PythonLibs "${PYTHON_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PYTHON_VERSION_MINOR}" REQUIRED)
```

That seems to do the trick. Thanks Dirk!

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2014-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-06-30**:
reported: https://github.com/ros/rospack/pull/42

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2014-09-18**:
wow after about 4 hours of trying to find a solution, i find this and it instantly works. Thanks!!!

**Comment by [rebcabin](https://answers.ros.org/users/19705/rebcabin/) on 2014-11-25**:
It did work for rospack, but not for qt_gui_core, which had the same missing PYTHON symbols error, but not an easy-to-see-fix in CMakeLists.txt  (I had to remove qt_gui_core to get the rest of the build unblocked)